# mitmweb on windows server 2008 R2 "The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located" error

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2008-r2, mitmproxy, system-error

I have installed mitmproxy as usual on my **Windows Server 2008 R2** machine.
When I try to run the program, It terminates and shows the message box:

> "The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in
>   the dynamic link lybrary api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll"

This is an important server that I can not reset.
Is there a solution ?

have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that our binaries only work on more recent Windows version. You may be more lucky with one the other mitmproxy installation methods: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/master/overview-installation/